How to apply assets from package in structure like mono repo in flutter?

I have a structure like this in my project.
I am running my project from "apps/medsurf_app/main_development.dart"
import 'package:abc_core/app/config/env_configs.dart';
import 'package:abc_core/app/enum.dart';
import 'package:abc_core/dev/main_development.dart' as entry;
import 'package:medsurf_app/firebase_options_dev.dart';

void main() => entry.mainCore(
      envConfigs: EnvConfigs(
        appName: 'name',
        currentEnv: Env.development,
        firebaseOptions: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
        iosAppId: '',
        androidPackageName: 'package',
      ),
    );

entry.mainCore Connects to "packages/abc_core/main_development.dart"
In short, my code base is inside "abc_core" and there will be multiple apps from "apps".
All the apps related config will be inside "apps" like firebase config and Android/iOS folders and all will be working fine.
Now I want my assets needs to be loaded dynamically from "apps/medsurf_app" to "packages/abc_core".
Like in future I have multiple apps and the code base will be the same only configs can change.
Please guide me into this How can I load assets from apps to abc_core?
